# Identify last item in alpine.js for loop

Tags: alpine.js

I have a for loop in my alpine.js code

```
<template x-for="(value, index, collection) in forecastQ4Values" :key="index">
   <div class="..."><span x-text="value"></span></div>
</template>
```

How can I add a class only to the last item in the for loop?
Basically I want to hide the last element until some variable changes.

For instance like this, but only on the last item.

```
<template x-for="(value, index, collection) in forecastQ4Values" :key="index">
   <div :class="{ 'invisible': !productDActive }" class="..."><span x-text="value"></span></div>
</template>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have access to index my first thought would be to check where you are in the loop. Like so:

```
<template x-for="(value, index, collection) in forecastQ4Values" :key="index">
   <div :class="{ 'invisible': (forecastQ4Values.size == index+1) }" class="..."><span x-text="value"></span></div>
</template>
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a lot, didn't realise you could add more logic in that :class.
:class="{ 'invisible': (forecastQ4Values.length == index+1 && !productDActive) }" does the trick!

Comment: forecastQ4Values.size -> this doesn't return any value though. Has to be .length
forecastQ3Values.length == index+1 -> this works

Comment: Right. It depends. If you iterate an array, collection then length and for a map use size.